# Blank frame inbetween SpriteKit infinite animaton

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to get an infinite action working in spritekit, I wrote the following:

```
func defaultAnimation() {
    let frames = Array((1..<13).map{SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/hero/\($0)")})
    let move = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame:0.25)
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(move))
}
```

The animation itself looks good, however there is a blank frame inbetween my frame set each time it repeats, please [see the gif](http://www.gfycat.com/PinkNextDutchshepherddog). I know it's not a missing resource, as the placeholder red x image is not displayed. What's going on here? The class with the function `defaultAnimation` inherits from `SKSpriteNode`, the hero folder contains my png sprites for the action I want (walking).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the hero is being drawn behind the background during the frames that it is not visible. If two sprites have the same `zPosition`...

> The rendering order may change each time a new frame is rendered.

To correct this, try setting

```
hero.zPosition = 1
```

and

```
background.zPosition = -1
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.